How to restrict access to Login Route if user is already logged in, using CanActivateFn?
I have successfully implement AuthGuardService which restrict access to a protected route if user is not logged in.
What I am trying to achieve is, if user is already logged in and accessed the Login Route, I want it to redirect to another route like homepage.
I am using CanActivateFn can anyone help me, pls
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../login-service/login-service.service';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
export const login_authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
const login_service = inject(LoginService);
const router = inject(Router);
return login_service.authenticatedLogin().pipe(
map(() => {
  return true;
}),
catchError(() => {
  router.navigate(['/login']);
  return of(false);
})
);
return false;
};


which result of the restriction do you want ? I think that the logical way is to redirect to the login form.

I would like to redirect to home page,path '/'

You can create guestGuard.
export const guestGuard: CanActivateFn & CanActivateChildFn = async () => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
    await router.navigate(['/']);

    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

In your case it would be something like this (not tested, so correct me if I'm wrong). I assume that isAuthenticated() returns Observable<boolean>.
export const guestGuard: CanActivateFn & CanActivateChildFn = () => {
  const loginService = inject(LoginService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return loginService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
    tap((isAuthenticated) => {
      if (isAuthenticated) router.navigate(['/']);
    }),
   )
};

And then use it for auth components:
{
  component: LoginComponent,
  path: 'login',
  canActivate: [guestGuard],
}


I tried this code, but i got this error at the guestGuard
"Type '() => Promise<Observable>' is not assignable to type 'CanActivateFn & CanActivateChildFn."

Oh sure, delete async. I copied it from previous example and forgot to delete.
